# Tinkerpop Gremlin transaction processor with bytecode?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I'm using the Gremlin language to query [JanusGraph](https://janusgraph.org/) (and other database systems) and I'm typically sending my queries in the `ByteCode` format using the [`traversal` op processor](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/dev/provider/#_traversal_opprocessor). However, for some queries, I need transactions (aka sessions) to batch multiple reads/writes, and for that I should be using the [`session` op processor](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/dev/provider/#_session_opprocessor).

The problem - the `traversal` processor accepts queries in gremlin bytecode, whereas the `session` op processor accepts queries as gremlin strings. Is there any way in which I can make queries which are both transactional (as I need a sequence of multiples reads and writes), and are sent as `ByteCode`?

I'm mainly asking since I discovered that queries running as ByteCode via the `traversal` processor, have significantly lower overhead time than the same queries being ran as strings with other processors (about 30ms difference).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: stephen mallette, i think there exist some solution even through not perfect currently. please refer: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2252 and i also think session is essential because many user need this ability，and noe4j and many other systems also support session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TinkerPop 3.5.0 it seems they did add bytecode transaction support: https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#transactions